# c++/error: no matching function for call to

Tags: c++, function, compiler-errors

I know its rather basic but, Im not quite sure what seems to be the problem with my functions arguments, but i keep getting the error: " no matching function for call to 'input' and 'summation'".

```
void Input (int **&x, int *&arr, int &size1,int &size2)
{
    cout << "Please enter 2 non-negative integer values: "<< endl;
    cout << "1. ";
    cin >> size1;
    int checkVal(int size1);
    cout << "2. ";
    cin >> size2;
    int checkVal(int size2);

    void putArr(int **&x,const int &s1,const int &s2);

    arr[0] = size1;
    arr[1] = size2;

}

void summation(int ***&y, int *&arr)
{
    int *size = new int;

    *size = **y[0] + **y[1];
    y[2] = new int *(size);

    *(arr + 2) = *size;

    delete size;

}

int main()
{
    int size, size1, size2;
    int size3;

    int** x;
    int*** y;
    int** q;
    int**** z;

    int *arr[2];

    allocArr(x, y, q, z);

    checkVal(size);

    Input(x, arr, size1, size2);

    putArr(x, size1, size2);


    summation(y, arr);

    display(z);


}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You need to declare the functions before you use them.

Comment: As @juanchopanza says, you need to declare those functions. Either forward-declare them at the top of the file or, better yet, put them in a separate header file.

Comment: That is a lot of `*`

Comment: http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ThreeStarProgrammer

Answer (score 1):

Both functions have a `int *&arr` parameter and you are passing in `arr` which is `int *[2]` so the parameters don't match.  You need to pass in `arr[0]` or `arr[1]` depending on what you are trying to do.

Comment: Valuable lesson: if you use that many levels of pointers, you _will_ make a mistake.